# How do I center a view in a grouped UITableViewCell on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I'm converting an iPhone app to the iPad and I'm getting stuck on an innocent and seemingly trivial positioning problem. I have a UITableViewCell that only contains a UISwitch, centered in the cell. The cell is in a UITableView with the Grouped style.

On the iPhone, I merely set the center property of the switch to the center of the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. <strike>That suffices for the iPhone because the center of the cell is the same regardless of table style.</strike> This happens on the iPhone too, but the offset is smaller, so the difference is more subtle. Here's the code for the iPhone:

```
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UISwitch *view = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [view addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    view.center = cell.center;        
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
    [view release];
```

On the iPad, without changing any code, the position of the switch is still in the center of an iPhone screen. That's bad, since iPad is way bigger than iPhone. So I moved the positioning code to `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and now it's on the other side of center (closer to the right side of the screen).

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UISwitch *s = (UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:SwitchTag];
s.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.center.x,s.center.y); //pushes the switch too far to the right
```

}

And yet, when I log the various coordinates and frames that I'm interested in, I get what I expect: the x coordinate of the center of the cell is at 384.0 which is half the screen width. I've also tried recalculating the whole frame of the UISwitch, but since I'm using the values of the screen, the switch ends up in the same spot, too far to the right.

What I *think* is going on is that there is some transform after `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is called (or before, even) to render all those numbers meaningless. It almost looks as if the whole cell gets shifted by *x*, where *x* is the distance from the edge of the screen to the start of the cell, even though that's  not reported in the `frame` property.

I'm sure there's something trivial I'm missing. Please enlighten me.

Comment: The center property is measured in the coordinate system of its superview. cell.contentView is the switch's superview, not the cell. Have you tried using cell.contentView.center instead of cell.center? Maybe check if there's a difference between the frames of the cell and the cell's contentView.

Comment: Tried that. The contentView and cell both have the same bounds. But you're right about the cell.center not being the correct value. I've updated the code since I went back to the iPhone and noticed the same problem, only more subtle.

Comment: I've had problems with tableview cell's before, especially in grouped tableview's. What you can do is create a subclass of UITableViewCell and override the layoutSubviews method.

Comment: Try setting the autoresizing masks to none, so that it stays in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't the most elegant solution and certainly doesn't start to get into the underlying behavior of why things aren't where you expect them to be in messing with tableCell views BUT

```
view.center =CGPointMake(tableView.center.x-(view.frame.size.width/2), cell.center.y) ;
```

if you use that line instead of the one you have posted it should happily (at least it looks that way in my fast tests) place thats switch in the middle of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Grouped cells work a little bit differently. I've had a similar problem but you are assuming things about center.  Sometimes setting the background color temporarily for all kinds of different views (cell.backgroundColor, cell.contentView.backgroundColor, etc) will help you visualize it a little better.

You might have to do something like this:

```
s.center = CGPointMake(s.superview.bounds.size.width / 2.0,s.center.y);
```

If that doesn't work, I believe you are right and it is doing something to the coordinates when it renders. If that's the case, then you'll have to write your own UITableViewCell subclass, which isn't the worst thing in the world.